# NSPredicate Contains with List

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a list of tags like item 1, item 2 and I want to use an NSPredicate to filter an array if a field matches anything in those items. This doesn't accomplish it:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags CONTAINS[c] %@", tag];
results = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the IN operator followed by the array of tags.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags IN %@", theTags];
```